# Illustrator: select all objects inside a path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

I have a big number, more then 100K, objects and would like to select all lying inside a path (big circle in my case). I don't want a clipping mask because I will end up with partial objects. I need whole ones. Any clues?

Comment: Unfortunately, Illustrator does not have a "select within" function. It's been a long standing oversight on Adobe's part.

Comment: Astute Graphics has a large suite of Illustrator plugins- they do cost money but also have a free trial period. One of their plugins (Collider Scribe) has the "Super Marquee" Tool and it can do exactly what you want. They have youtube videos about it. I have no affiliation with them (except as a customer) but always jump at the chance to tell people how great their plugins are.